# Make an API call inside didTapMarker to get the marker title and assign it after response is received in Google Maps API for iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying to make an API call inside the `didTapMarker` function. After the call is done, I am trying to set the `marker.title` but it does not work. The call is an asynchronous one and I think that somehow related to the problem. Next time I tap the marker it shows the result, but not after the first tap.

Here is the code,

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker!) -> Bool {
    if marker.title == nil{
        makeApiRequest(["id": marker.userData],
            success: {
                (response: Dictionary<String, JSONValue>?) in
                if let name = response?["name"]?.string{
                    marker.title = name
                }
            },
            failure: {
                (error: NSError) in
        })
    }
}
```

Please help. How should I be doing this to make it work in the first tap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `self.mapView` (assume self.mapView is your instance variable)

And do `self.mapView .selectedMarker = marker` right below `marker.title = name`

If your response block still not in the main UI thread, you can update your mapView in the main UI thread

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    marker.title = name
    self.mapView.selectedMarker = marker
}
```

Comment: That worked! Yay! Thanks. :) It is in the main thread so didn't have to use `dispatch_async`.